# What else is required to learn a Overdrive Mode

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I was looking at [this link](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Overdrive_Mode) for unlocking overdrive modes however I am confused, according to it Tidas's should obtain Healer before Warrior however Warrior was the first one I got.

So I am wondering, are there other conditions for obtaining overdrive modes in addition to turns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Overdrive Mode is associated with a specific activity in two ways - first, you need to perform that activity enough turns (or, in some cases, have activities performed against you and your party often enough) to earn the Overdrive Mode; then, once you've earned the mode and assigned it to the character, performing that activity will fill the Overdrive gauge.

In your case, your Tidus has damaged an enemy at least 150 times, but not yet healed another character 80 times.

A single turn (or enemy's turn) should count for multiple modes at a time, I believe - for example, if you attack and kill an enemy to win the battle, it should count for Warrior, Slayer, Victor, and Ally.